# Getting data from a specific row in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, datetime

I have the below SQL query which returns a result containing financial transactions on a loan, made on specific dates...

```
$data = array( 'loan_id'=>130 );
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM ledger WHERE loan_id = :loan_id");
$STH->execute($data);
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$row = $STH->fetchAll(); 

print_r($row);
```

This gives the following result

```
Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( 
        [ledger_id] => 38 
        [loan_id] => 130 
        [ledger_type_id] => 1 
        [amount] => 1.20 
        [ledger_date] => 2016-07-25 
    ) 

 [1] => Array ( 
        [ledger_id] => 39 
        [loan_id] => 130 
        [ledger_type_id] => 3 
        [amount] => 0.90 
        [ledger_date] => 2016-08-15 
    ) 

 [2] => Array ( 
        [ledger_id] => 40 
        [loan_id] => 130 
        [ledger_type_id] => 2 
        [amount] => 0.30 
        [ledger_date] => 2016-09-19 
    ) 
)
```

I now need to loop through all dates that the loan has been active, and find the 'ledger_type_id' and 'amount' for transactions that occurred on the current date in the loop. The ledger table does not contain a record for every day, however I need to look at each individual day that the loan has been active for other purposes not relevant to this question.

```
$start_date = new DateTime('2016-07-13');
$today = new DateTime();
$today = $today->modify( '+1 day' ); // add one day to include today
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D'); 
$daterange = new DatePeriod($start_date, $interval ,$today);

foreach ($daterange as $date) {

    /*  
       The above SQL query returns a row with the 'ledger_date' 
       of '2016-08-15'

       I need to find the value of the ledger_type_id 
       for the same row from the above query 
       when $date = '2016-08-15' in this loop
    */

    // Do other unrelated stuff on each day of the loop.....

}
```

I have tried a few things using in_array() but without success.

Comment: but why all this complications. Why not juse look at the ledger_date ??

Comment: Why not just use `AND ledger_date BETWEEN 2016-07-13 AND whatever`??? Or `WHERE ledger_date = '2016-08-15'`

Comment: Because I need to loop through every date for other reasons, and the ledger table does not have records on every day. I have editied the question to explain this more clearly

Comment: By the way. Ive tried looping through the query results in each iteration of the date loop and using an if statement to isolate the query data for a given day. This works fine however it seems a bit of a waste of resources

Answer (score 0):

When you're working in SQL and you think *I need a loop,* that should have you think, *wait a minute.* SQL is declarative, not procedural.

In SQL, the question of handling every day in a date range is usually done with a table (physical or virtual) containing all the days. We can call it the `calendar` table.   Then we can `LEFT JOIN` the table with actual data to that table.  In your example:

```
SELECT calendar.day, ledger.*
  FROM calendar
  LEFT JOIN ledger ON calendar.day = ledger.date
 WHERE loan_id = :loan_id
 ORDER BY calendar.day, ledger.id
```

This will give a result set with *at least one row* for each calendar day.

The trick is to get an appropriate `calendar` table.   Here's a way to do that.

```
             SELECT mintime + INTERVAL seq.seq DAY AS day
               FROM (
                       SELECT MIN(DATE(ledger.date)) AS mintime,
                              MAX(DATE(ledger.date)) AS maxtime
                         FROM ledger
                    ) AS minmax
               JOIN seq_0_to_999999 AS seq 
                 ON seq.seq < TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,mintime,maxtime)
```

This will give you a virtual table (subquery) covering the range of dates in your ledger.

So you query will look like this:

```
SELECT calendar.day, ledger.*
  FROM (
             SELECT mintime + INTERVAL seq.seq DAY AS day
               FROM (
                       SELECT MIN(DATE(ledger.date)) AS mintime,
                              MAX(DATE(ledger.date)) AS maxtime
                         FROM ledger
                    ) AS minmax
               JOIN seq_0_to_999999 AS seq 
                 ON seq.seq < TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,mintime,maxtime)
       ) calendar
  LEFT JOIN ledger ON ledger.date >= calendar.day
                  AND ledger.date < calendar.day + INTERVAL 1 DAY
 WHERE loan_id = :loan_id
 ORDER BY calendar.day, ledger.id
```

If you happen to be using the [MariaDB fork](https://mariadb.org/about/) of MySQL, the handy-dandy table `seq_0_to_999999` is predefined for you as a [sequence table](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sequence/). Otherwise you can create it easily as a series of views, like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS seq_0_to_9;
CREATE TABLE seq_0_to_9 AS
   SELECT 0 AS seq UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9;
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS seq_0_to_999;
CREATE VIEW seq_0_to_999 AS (
SELECT (a.seq + 10 * (b.seq + 10 * c.seq)) AS seq
  FROM seq_0_to_9 a
  JOIN seq_0_to_9 b
  JOIN seq_0_to_9 c
);
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS seq_0_to_999999;
CREATE VIEW seq_0_to_999999 AS (
SELECT (a.seq + (1000 * b.seq)) AS seq
  FROM seq_0_to_999 a
  JOIN seq_0_to_999 b
);
```

I have more on this topic at http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/filling-missing-data-sequences-cardinal-integers/